# Pure Data: How can I get the difference between two subsequent numbers

Tags: puredata

Beginner Pd user here.  I have a number message, and I am trying to get the numerical difference between the current number and the previous number - does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way to do it:

[image]

If you need the absolute difference, use the object **abs** before the final result (to ignore the negative sign).